# W3C RSA-SHA256 algorithm cannot be used, unsupported algorithm

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, digital-signature, rsa-sha256

Is anyone also having trouble with the W3C RSA-SHA256 algorithm to sign XML ?
I'm using it to do a XML Digital Signature but I'm not able to use it since the page has been moved, see:
[https://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256](https://stackoverflow.com)

I'm forced to used the RSA-SHA1 which I don't want to use because it's stated as deprecated for my purpose and I cannot validate the crate securely with the SHA1.

Any solution on how to use the SHA256 ?

Thanks

I'm using it like this:
`SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256", null), references);`

And I get the error `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unsupported algorithm`.

I used different sources such as Oracle doc or [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/xml-digital-signature-cryptographic-algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com) and as you can see in the last one, many of them are unusable !

Comment: yes, `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256` appears to be [the right string](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jcp/xml/dsig/internal/dom/DOMSignatureMethod.java.html), have you tried it? Apparently also available as a `RSA_SHA256` named constant.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used `SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256` and apparently it worked. I always thought I had to put an actual URI as algorithm, thank you

Comment: Great, let's make that into an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jcp/xml/dsig/internal/dom/DOMSignatureMethod.java.html

the 2001 string is correct `http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256` instead of your 2000 one.

Or you can use the `SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256` constant which should resolve to the same thing.